# Unable to query remote server with Qwinsta command using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

The script below is currently configured to perform Qwinsta from multiple online servers, and then send the result as email.

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format 'F'
$SessionList = "`n`nRDP Session List - " + $Today + "`n`n"
$CurrentSN = 0

# Get a list of servers from Active Directory
write-progress -activity "Getting list of servers from Active Directory" -status "... please wait ..."

$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter { Enabled -eq $True -and OperatingSystem -like "*Server*" } -SearchBase "OU=servers,dc=dwlab02,dc=local" | Where-Object { Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$NumberOfServers = $Servers.Count

# Iterate through the retrieved list to check RDP sessions on each machine
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {

    $ServerName = $Server.Name
    Write-progress -activity "Checking RDP Sessions" -status "Querying $ServerName" -percentcomplete (($CurrentSN / $NumberOfServers) * 100)

    # Run qwinsta and grab the output
    try {
        $queryResults = (qwinsta /server:$ServerName | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+", ",")) } | convertfrom-csv -ErrorAction Stop)

        # get session info from the instance
        ForEach ($QueryResult in $QueryResults) {

            $RDPUser = $($QueryResult.substring(19, 22)).trim()
            $SessionType = $($QueryResult.substring(1, 18)).trim()
            $SessionID = $($QueryResult.substring(41, 5)).trim()
            $ReturnedCurrentState = $($QueryResult.substring(48, 8)).trim()

            $RDPUser = $QueryResult.USERNAME
            $SessionType = $QueryResult.SESSIONNAME
            $SessionID = $QueryResult.ID
            $ReturnedCurrentState = $QueryResult.State

            If ($ReturnedCurrentState -eq $null) { $CurrentState = "Disconnected" } Else { $CurrentState = "Active" }

            # filter out the irrelevant information
            If (($RDPUser -ne $NULL) -and ($SessionType -ne "console") -and ($SessionType -ne "services") -and ($SessionType -ne "rdp-tcp") -and ($RDPUser -ne "65536")) {
                $SessionList = $SessionList + "`n" + $ServerName + " logged in by " + $RDPUser + " on " + $SessionType + ", session id $SessionID $CurrentState"
            }
        }

    }
    catch {
        $SessionList = $SessionList + "`n Unable to query " + $ServerName
        write-host "Unable to query $ServerName!" -foregroundcolor Red
    }

    $CurrentSN++
}

# Send the output the screen.
$SessionList + "`n`n"

$sendMailArgs = @{
    From       = 'sender@domain.com'
    To         = 'recipient@domain.com'
    Subject    = "$($SessionList.Count) Logged On users from $($NumberOfServers) online servers as at $($Today)"
    SmtpServer =    'smtp.office365.com'
    Port       = 587
    UseSsl     = $true
    Credential =    New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password)
}

Send-MailMessage @sendMailArgs -Body $SessionList
```

However, the result is always a blank email with the below content:

> RDP Session List - Monday, 17 August 2020 12:28:19 PM
>
> Unable to query   Unable to query   Unable to query   Unable to query
> Unable to query   Unable to query   Unable to query   Unable to query
> Unable to query

How can I fix the above script?

Comment: Add some verbose logging that outputs data at each step.  That will help you see where things are going wrong.

Comment: Change your log message to: `Write-Host "Unable to query $($ServerName): $($_.Exception.Message)"` to see the actual error

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue converting the project from Windows-Legacy, to Windows, now i'm able to run the powershell script, and also get the info from the active session with qwinsta.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by converting the project from Windows-Legacy?